# Product description in transactional email Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am using `magento 1.9.1` and the e-mail templates. I came with the following code, which should display the product description in transactional e-mails.

`<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>`

However it does not do that. Does anyone know if somewhere else in the code the description must be loaded first?

Greetings, Marcel

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());?>
<?php echo $_product->getDescription();?>
```